# How to clear/teardown db with pytest in Flask app

Tags: database, flask, pytest

I know this might seem like duplication, I have found similar questions on SO on this topic, but none of them really worked for me. I simply need to clear out (or teardown) the database after each test, so every test works with a new empty one.

I am using fixture and my code looks like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def test_client_db():

    # set up
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///"
    with app.app_context():
        db.init_app(app)
        db.create_all()
    testing_client = app.test_client() 
    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()

    # do the testing
    yield testing_client

    # tear down
    with app.app_context():
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

    ctx.pop()
```

I am new to pytest and from what I have learnt, whatever goes before yield works as sort of a "set up", whatever goes after works as "teardown". Yet, when I run several tests, the database is not clear for each test, it holds data between them.

Why is it so? What is wrong with this fixture? What am i missing?

Comment: You have a module level fixture, meaning that the teardown is only executed once in every test module. If you want it after each test, use function scope (which is the default if you don't set a scope).

Comment: oh, thank you. it works!

Answer (score 2):

You have set the scope to `module` - this means the fixture will only be reset after all tests in a module had run.

Either set the scope to `function` or leave it completely, as `function` is the default.

See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#fixture-scopes